# Why can I select a row in one data grid, but not the other?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two `DataGrid`s:

```
<DataGrid Name="grdDailyOne"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeRows="False"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="From"
                            Binding="{Binding From}"
                            MinWidth="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="To"
                            Binding="{Binding To}"
                            MinWidth="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Elapsed Time"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="HDDC Codes"
                            Binding="{Binding HDDCCode}"
                            MinWidth="250" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Details of Operations in Sequence and Remarks"
                            Binding="{Binding Details}"
                            MinWidth="250" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rot Ftg"
                            Binding="{Binding RotFtg}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Slide Ftg"
                            Binding="{Binding SlideFtg}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          Name="grid1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          FontSize="25"
          Margin="10,20,10,40"
          CanUserResizeRows="False"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product"
                            Binding="{Binding Product}" />

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount"
                            Binding="{Binding Amount}" />

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Units"
                            Binding="{Binding Units}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now, in the one on the bottom, I can select rows just fine, but the top one, I cannot. I've looked through, and all the properties are the same. I do know at one point, I was able to do so, but now I'm not. Is there a property that I'm missing that I need to set?

I have tried using `SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow"`, but still nothing.

Comment: @Omribitan: Tried that, to no avail.

Comment: Maybe its not the grid itself that prevents you from selection but it's container? have you looked into that?

Comment: @Omribitan: That was indeeded the case. I had the grid in a `tab control`, which had the `SelectionChanged` event set. I removed that, and viola! It worked. Thank you.